# Unable to obtain results with Business Google V3 API

Tags: python, google-maps-api-3

The example's keys below have been deleted/removed.

Facts: 
My account is setup for billing. 
My account has the API enabled. 
The values match(ed) up with what I received from google. 
When the outputted URL I get a 403.

Below is my code.   Any clues as to why this isn't working.  I've tried using googles own code and youtube videos to no prevail.

```
>>> import sys
>>> import hashlib
>>> import urllib
>>> import hmac
>>> import base64
>>> import urlparse
>>>
>>> print("")

>>> print("URL Signer 1.0")
URL Signer 1.0
>>> print("")

>>>
>>> # Collect the URL input string (which must alrady be URL-encoded)
... # from the user and parse it into its collective components
... # For testing purposes, if no URL is entered, we use a default
... inputStr = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=New+Yor
k&client=2863356457-btgvd8ij9n51p3p8h240foam0ea4010q.apps.googleusercontent.com"

>>>
>>> print("URL To Sign: " + inputStr)
URL To Sign: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=New+York&c
lient=2863356457-btgvd8ij9n51p3p8h240foam0ea4010q.apps.googleusercontent.com
>>> url = urlparse.urlparse(inputStr)
>>>
>>> privateKey = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIICdgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCA
mAwggJcAgEAAoGBAJ6MlHDfA3XFHoUi\n4gWiAOEH5Jyat8hZEGrPw7ABxzH4b1GiaVij7iDZWH09cfj
OFMF0Z8N3i3A4xlMl\n5l+gd7pI7egEuItGHVrbM8aTTVbDVWIfKh+8Cp4y9HuB+xAznPNArQs7Am1gv
hkJ\neoMij1GbcPLV7Wt0Pn87jIcxv9TpAgMBAAECgYBfCN7VRSf6yLwBi6Y1QCUMvcFv\niWHN6mzny
T9/2aD/t+1p3lMM+b373Kuo7lLJkyVnzBGCXb6r9qwSHO6YtUPt6J0q\n3wLIxRZXL7gztgjxGHCb1zC
HBCLXBQnit0cvsnTuXe+B40n5PWZoBKcQP6O2RBU8\nlDIClBP9+2tjT/eJsQJBANHrnN/W8Cyf0cvrL
bH3epMwLvs3UlxvA4wD0C0oPjqQ\nLHOncaRg+VQ32RJYP6zHo4PUmgW+JgwDBrppVj0wlG0CQQDBWi7
BczFieLENkS9n\nbyNSuAw+LR0EhEkzAbFaEEzMLXP5GI1P4pKIOpfsI7Km4mtNgGKu8e+0NvKZzRsa\
nJJztAkBh2ddNS+62jmUIDf9F5ts/QwWTWo1Mwv6/RIPEmO6w88WUv6esfPub81B/\nSZ2c1450BCUrq
iAoFz0KpdFqQnvdAkBJy5auxL1jfPbuW6xBCPztVEtv6534nFin\nvAypeDEneG2b88/zXmFY1ywmt1U
3NpGHqemAJdy75oDfTJX8e17dAkEAo/jVBhha\n9P3Vg5zrIGktnfKpw2E33jHucCNktQriCjDGDChYL
eglSMhXthYhHw3v495WLSEy\nkcR5BCwHXHA98A\u003d\u003d\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n
"
>>>
>>> print("Private Key: " + privateKey)
Private Key: -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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\u003d\u003d
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

>>>
>>> #We only need to sign the path+query part of the string
... urlToSign = url.path + "?" + url.query
>>> print("")

>>> print("Original Path + Query: " + urlToSign)
Original Path + Query: /maps/api/geocode/json?address=New+York&client=2863356457
-btgvd8ij9n51p3p8h240foam0ea4010q.apps.googleusercontent.com
>>>
>>> # Decode the private key into its binary format
... # We need toe decode the URL-encoded private key
... decodedKey = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(privateKey)
>>>
>>> # Create a signature using the private key and the URL-encoded
... # string using HMAC SHA1. This signature will be binary.
... signature = hmac.new(decodedKey, urlToSign, hashlib.sha1)
>>>
>>> # Encode the binary signature into base64 for use within a URL
... encodedSignature = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(signature.digest())
>>> print("")

>>> print("B64 Signature: " + encodedSignature)
B64 Signature: bbMQO235878mM7lO0jQukCagwb8=
>>> originalUrl = url.scheme + "://" + url.netloc + url.path + "?" + url.query
>>> print("")

>>> print("Full URL: " + originalUrl + "&signature=" + encodedSignature)
Full URL: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=New+York&clie
nt=2863356457-btgvd8ij9n51p3p8h240foam0ea4010q.apps.googleusercontent.com&signat
ure=bbMQO235878mM7lO0jQukCagwb8=
>>>
```

Comment: Don't you have support available from Google with the Business API?

Comment: @geocodezip I would if I upgraded to the GOLD package.  That costs $400/month so I'm not that excited especially when I only want to geocode 250k addresses.

Comment: I don't know much about Maps API for Business but it might be useful to add to your question the output of your different prints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with [smarty streets](http://smartystreets.com) a way better solution with a lot of cool geo data along with the address.